# Which local IP address should OpenVPN listen on?

Tags: openvpn

I am working on setting my the server.ovpn and have a question. The first item in the config file says "Which local IP address should OpenVPN listen on? (optional)."

1. Which IP address should I put in here? The IP address of my server? Or the IP address of the router?
2. Why is this optional? Does OpenVPN attempt to determine it automatically? What is the default value?

I have been reading through some of the documentation here https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html but haven't been able to find answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its suppose to be the ip address of where the openvpn will be listening. so in your example if you have 1 computer, 1 server and 1 router then it should be the ip address of your server since you mentionned you want to setup your openvpn on your server

if you dont know whats the IP address just go in your command prompt and type "ipconfig". be aware though that if you PC is on a dhcp config from your router then i would suggest either use a static ip and assign it to your computer or just go in your router and reserve your computer ip address so it wont change.

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've installed OpenVPN on my home desktop and am configuring it as a server. So in this case, the IP address that OpenVPN should be listening to is the IP address of this computer (that it is running on)?

Comment: yes it is. the ip address of your computer should be the one you should enter. then if I was you, go in your router and reserve you're ip address so your router always gives you that exact ip address. the reason is if you don't do this and you're router gives you a different one from your openvpn, then your vpn wont work